# Hibernate criteria equivalent for "not in" with join

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I'm trying to do a "not in" query with Hibernate (4.3.6) criteria, but I do not want to use

`// get session, create criteria, etc.
...
Restrictions.not(Restrictions.in( ... ))
...`

My entity situation is the following:

**Report** with its *id* and a list of *AcceptedReport*

**AcceptedReport** with the *Report.id* reference and *idModerator*

My query (in natural language) should be: "All the *Report* which are not yet accepted by the specified moderator"

How could I do this query using only joins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this, it should work in your exact situation:

```
return (List<Report>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
.createCriteria(Report.class, "AllReport")
.createAlias("AllReport.acceptedReports", "AcceptedReport",
    //This is waht you were probably missing
    JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN,
    Restrictions.eq("AcceptedReport.idmoderator", idModerator) 
)
.add(Restrictions.isNull("AcceptedReport.idModerator"))
.list();
```